# How to dynamically visualize $3$-spheres?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am no mathematician, but I am really curious.

In my limited knowledge (for the sake of analogy, the following paragraph may sound strange), I know:

A point is $0$-sphere, it is the surface of $1$-ball (a segment); A circle is $1$-sphere, it is the surface of $2$-ball (a disk); A sphere is $2$-sphere, it is the surface of $3$-ball (a ball); A $3$-phere is the surface of $4$-ball. An $n$-sphere is a set of points with distance from a point equal to a length in $n+1$ dimensions, it has finite $n$-area and borderless in $n$ dimensions, infinity to the power of $n$ (I know it's still the same...thing) axes of symmetry, and you can travel in any direction tangent to it in $n$ dimensions without changing direction forever. $n$-sphere is the intersection of $(n+1)$-sphere and $(n+1)$-plane, as the $(n+1)$-sphere moves through the $(n+1)$-plane, $n$-sphere's radius starts at $0$, increases until reaching radius of $(n+1)$-sphere and decreases until reaching $0$ again(and after that becomes non-existent).

And that's all I know. I had found this image on Wikipedia, and I really can't quite understand it:

[image]

My brain really isn't evolved to deal with higher dimensions, will somebody please make some gif files to dynamically visualize how $3$-spheres rotate, and explain it like I am five? And please use perspective projection.

Comment: Higher dimensional objects are purely mathematical constructions. You're not going to get a nice intuitive and visual explanation without any mathematics because such an explanation doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this nice video of the Hopf fibration to visualize a sphere in 4 dimension.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKotMPGFJYk

Of course to understand it you need some knowledge of what a bundle is, but see it in this way: in the video you see different parts of the 4-sphere.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it is a good visualization indeed, but there were no explanations, and I still don't understand it...

Comment: As I told you, to understand it you need to know about fiber bundles (take it like a good motivation to study mathematics ;) ). The main intuition you can draw is the following: it is possible, in some sense, to build a function that to every point in $S^2$ associates a circle in $S^3$. This is what the video is showing: circumferences over $S^3$. It is not possible to see them together since it is a four-dimensional object, but still something can be done in 3D, that is to see the circumference that lie on it.

Comment: Well, there has been use of the quaternions in various types of computing, as a compact way to deal with rotations in ordinary three-space. In turn, the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^4$ becomes an accessible object. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation ........"Thus, a simple way of visualizing the Hopf fibration is as follows. Any point on the 3-sphere is equivalent to a quaternion, which in turn" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration   ....